# Can mods notify each other from the different posts in the form of flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools, moderators

Considering, that nobody can see flags except mods, a flag raised by a mod could serve as a mod-only, only mod-visible notification to a post.

I am thinking on notes like this:

1. *"To avoid whining, I suggest to delete this post silently a month later"*.
2. *"X made also a related trouble, check this <link>"*.
3. *"Y wrote already some very similar, I asked the team to investigate"*.

Doing this would be an easy way for the mod community for a coherent behavior. For example, (1) could avoid that after a lesser vehement mod reviewed a case, a more vehement mod makes a deletion. In the view of the community, the mods could show a more coherent face.

Although the mods have mod-only communication channels, these don't belong to induvidual posts. Having the ability to attach notes to the posts, visible only for the other mods, should likely significantly improve their effectivity and predictability.

Does it exist? Or maybe they are using some different method to notify eachother?

Comment: It's like policemen will exchange private messages via police reports. It's not meant to be this way. Instead, there are private moderator-only chat rooms, where they can discuss exactly those things.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, but these chat messages aren't bound to the induvidual posts. If a mod see a post, he has no way to see the related chat messages.

Comment: They can do that with user accounts.

Comment: Are you a mod? If not why do you care anyway?

Comment: @DavidPostill It's not wrong for a non-mod to be curious. Happens to me all the time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, mods sometimes use flags to communicate with each other.**

Personally, as a mod, I haven't done this very much. A few occasions when I can remember doing it:

- flagging something as "*not an answer*" when I'm not sure and want a second opinion;
- flagging something for mod action which would be a conflict of interest if I did it (e.g. if I answered an exact duplicate and my answer is good enough to merge over to the original).

Issues such as your examples, which are going to take a long time to be resolved or which concern a particular *user*'s general behaviour rather than just a particular *post*, would normally be raised via **chat** instead. On my mod site, sometimes one mod will ping/superping the others in the site-specific mod chatroom about some issue, or some of us will have a discussion there about how to handle something. The advantage of chat is that it enables **back-and-forth dialogue**, which a flag doesn't really. Your concern about mods showing a "coherent face" is more easily resolved by different mods discussing among themselves how to handle an issue than by one mod flagging for the others.

My mod experience, however, is only from a single site. I know that mods on other sites *do* use flagging to leave notes for themselves/each other more extensively. Still, though, I doubt that your three examples would be a good use case for mod-mod-flagging even there. Maybe if the "month" in your first example was replaced by "day" or "few days".

Comment: For specific users it's better to use annotations.

Comment: @Catija Depends on the context. If it's "this user keeps doing X", then yes, annotate. If it's "hmm, should we suspend this user?", that might be worth a mod-to-mod discussion in chat.

Answer (score 11):

Nope, we don't.

It is an idea that sounds cool in *theory* but I'd rather not have things like that sitting in the flag queue. I like my flag queue clean.

If there's a trend, or a specific post that needs looking at, I leave it in chat (since transcripts work better).

Frankly, I sometimes use public chat to get eyeballs on things from normal users. The mod only communications channels, or even the public ones, work better in many cases.

Looking at the bigger picture:

> "To avoid whining, I suggest to delete this post silently a month later".

Never done it. If someone's going to whine, we deal with it on meta like grownups. Also sounds like a pain to review a bunch of old flags, or worse leave a flag in place for a month.

> "X made also a related trouble, check this <link>".

We can't search old flags. There's also a character limit. Wrong tool for the job, like trying to bash in nails with a wrench.

> "Y wrote already some very similar, I asked the team to investigate".

May need feedback and discussion - flags work terribly for this. We'd likely use a mix of other tools here.

Comment: Some mods *do* use flags as "come back and delete if they haven't improved", but only for a day or two, not a month.